# Passing java options to libjvm

Tags: java, embedding

My code uses a library which loads `libjvm.so` in order to embed some java code, essentially running the JVM within my process.

AFAIK normally when running with the `java` executable, one passes options through the command line arguments, Is there an equivalent when embedding `libjvm`?

I have already tried to use the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable, but without success. Is there another way? Maybe even a "canonical" way?

Comment: hmm, if you are going to down vote the question, can you at least be helpful enough to give a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I have found that although `JAVA_OPTS` does not work, there is another environment variable called `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` which is part of the `JVMTI` and seems to do the trick.

For more information take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html)